# Win Server 2003 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

Last week, our Windows 2003 Domain Controller crashed. We tried to restore using BKF files, but the server won't boot. Then one of our staff laptops locked, because it cannot connect to the Domain Controller.

How can I restore the Domain Controller and unlock the laptop?

Comment: How did you do the restore? Is this your only DC? How old is the backup? What do you mean that the laptop is locked? Computer accounts don't lock, user accounts do, but if your domain is unreachable, the failed logon attempts won't lock anything.

Comment: We reinstall win server 2003 then we restore using ***.bkf file from our server backup. After 100% complete win server asking to reboot. After rebooting win server only show win server logo so long without going any where. The laptop want get into user desktop as it is before.

Comment: When you did the reinstall, did you partition the drives and assign the letters the same as they were before? Did you restore to the same hardware? Was the restore that you did from a **full** backup? It sounds like you might need to hire someone that knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes that you only have 1 DC (which you shouldn't), but nothing in your question makes me think that you have more than one.

Put the Domain Controller into [Directory Services Restore Mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776568(WS.10).aspx). Then, restore the system from a known good backup. This will bring AD back to a previous state. After you have a functioning DC again, you can deal with the malfunctioning laptop like you would any other troublesome domain-joined computer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've had a catastrophic failure of your only Active Directory Domain Controller (DC). Presumably you have some kind of backup since you mentioned "BKF files".

Ideally we could have troubleshot the "crash" that you describe, however since you've already attempted restoration it's likely that you've damaged the operating system so much as to render troubleshooting useless.

Ideally you could set aside the hard disk drives in the server computer and perform your restore activities on fresh disks so that you have the option to attempt to recover files, etc, since the backup was last performed from the old disks. If you don't have that option then consider making copies of the disks in the server computer to a safe location before you proceed.

If you have a full backup of the DC's operating system *AND* the System State you can perform a bare metal restore of the machine. You would start by installing Windows Server 2003 on to the server computer. I'd format the disks and start "fresh". Once Windows is installed you can use NTBackup to restore the backups you previously took, including the "System State". Once you have restored the backup you will need to reboot the server computer into "Directory Services Restore Mode" and restore the System State again to restore Active Directory.

Comment: we do install onto new machine and restoring server using bkf file but seems win server wont boot on new machine. the sign only spinning for long time.

Comment: You will have bad luck restoring a Windows 2003 System State backup to different hardware than the original system. You need to restore onto hardware as close to the original as possible.

Comment: Not to be harsh, but luck has nothing to do with this. You only had 1 DC and you (apparently) have never tested your backups. That's your own fault.